# In what order / how does Scala evaluate conditionals inside a function definition?

Tags: scala, if-statement, conditional-statements

While trying to write a simple parentheses balancing function, I learned that I do not know how scala evaluates if-statements.

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  def loop(chars: List[Char], opened: Int): Boolean = {
    println(opened)
    println(chars.head)
    if (opened < 0) return false
    if (chars.isEmpty && opened == 0) return true
    if (chars.isEmpty && opened > 0) return false
    if (!chars.isEmpty && chars.head.toString == "(") loop(chars.tail, opened+1)
    if (!chars.isEmpty && chars.head.toString == ")") loop(chars.tail, opened-1)
    else loop(chars.tail, opened)
  }
loop(chars, 0)
}
```

When I run this, by the third iteration, it will println(opened) and claim opened = -1. I imagined that (opened < 0) ----> (-1 < 0) -----> true, so I will return false. This is not the case - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala evaluates `if` expressions in the order they are declared. The problem with this algo is that it is assuming that the last `else` expression will only be evaluated if no other `if` condition is true, but with an input '(X))'  you will create two recursion trees: one for the condition `!chars.isEmpty && chars.head.toString == "("` and another in `else loop(chars.tail, opened)`. That creates the impression that the recursion is not ending when opened =-1 but in fact what you are seeing is the 'else'  recursion tree.

Solution? You are just missing an `else`:

```
if (!chars.isEmpty && chars.head.toString == "(") loop(chars.tail, opened+1) **else**
```

(Note: this code can probably be improved using a `match...case` statement. That will prevent the previous `else` issue from happening. 
Also, you can compare chars with chars. No need to turn them into strings: `chars.head.toString == "("` => `chars.head == '('` )

*** EDIT ***
After your comment, here's how you could use pattern matching on your list structure:

```
def loop(chars: List[Char], opened: Int): Boolean = {
    if (opened < 0) return false else 
    chars match {
    case Nil => opened == 0
    case '('::tail => loop(tail, opened + 1)
    case ')'::tail => loop(tail, opened -1)
    case x::tail => loop(tail, opened)
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Instead I used a bunch of else if's.

Comment: @Cawb07 here you have your same loop logic using pattern matching. See how you can match not only on the structure (`head::tail`) but also on specific instantiations of it (`'('::tail)`). Good luck learning Scala.